# Magento 2 admin user role issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5, user-roles

I have Magento multi site setup, I have created a admin user role for a website and provided below config:
Role Scope: Selected only a website
Resource Acess: All

And assigned a user to that role.

Issue: When i go to store product attributes, i am not able to see Save attribute/Delete Attribute buttons. Please help

Comment: check your user role resources and allow eav permissions

Comment: Resource access is all for that user role.

Comment: i just checked creating new role it's working maybe you have any other issue

Comment: Have you given a particular website access to that user role with all resource and you are able to see save button in attributes? For a admin user associated to above user role

Comment: @Mehran Please check below link
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9337

Here i am referring point number 3 in actual result section.

Comment: any one has idea on it?